# Bootstrap components (javascript) not responding

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twig, mamp

Just a quick question and I am taking a bit of a stab in the dark here, I apologise if it is way to general.

My twitter bootstrap components such as my Dropdown menus and my Modals have suddenly stopped working. I stopped developing this project a few months ago and it was all working perfectly until recently I have gone back to development and they are not wanting to work. I have changed nothing since they used to work.

Has there been a recent update that could have caused this?

I am working with MAMP and Twig and PHP.

Thank you very much in advanced!

Comment: Bootstrap is in version 3 now.

Comment: Are you loading any of your javascript from an online link?  It's possible that the source where the link was directed to was changed.. Other then that I can't think of any reason it would just stop working.. Its true Bootstrap is now updated to version 3 but if your still using the old bootstrap source code it should work as it had before.

Comment: Yup I am loading it from online actually. Would this be what has changed? `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` ?

Comment: Since the link is version specific I don't think its likely that it has been changed..